# How does Scala's type inference work with type bounds?

Tags: scala, type-inference, type-bounds

When type bounds exist on a type parameter, how exactly does Scala determine the type to infer? For example:

```
def onMouseClicked_=[T >: MouseEvent](lambda: T => Unit) = 
  setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler[T] {
    override def handle(event: T): Unit = lambda(event)
  })
```

When attempting to use this function, such as in:

```
onMouseClicked = { me => doSomething() }
```

`me` will have the inferred type of `MouseEvent`. The type bound of `T` is a lower type bound, so `T` must either be of type `MouseEvent` or a supertype of `MouseEvent`, so why does `me` have the inferred type of `MouseEvent`? Shouldn't it infer the most general type?

Is it something I'm not getting about how Scala's type inference works? Or is my understanding of type bounds completely wrong?

Edit:

Let's say we further restrict the the type of T to be a subtype of `Event`, where `Event` is a supertype of `MouseEvent`. So we get:

```
def onMouseClicked_=[T >: MouseEvent <: Event](lambda: T => Unit) = 
  setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler[T] {
    override def handle(event: T): Unit = lambda(event)
  })
```

So if we do

```
onMouseClicked = { me: MouseDragEvent => doSomething() }
```

where `MouseDragEvent` is a subtype of `MouseEvent`, the compile fails with a type error, as expected, because the bound ensures that `me` must be a supertype of `MouseEvent`.

And yet if we do

```
onMouseClicked = { me: Any => doSomething() }
```

the compile succeeds. It's obvious that `Any` is not a subtype of `Event`, so why does the compile succeed? What is inferred type of `T`?

Answer (score 2):

I'll give this a try, but I'm not sure everything will be supercorrect or anyway clear.

#### Premise

The first point to address is that a function from type `T` to result `R` (`T => R`) is covariant in its return type and contravariant in its parameters: i.e. `Function[-T, +R]`.

To make it short it means that for function `fsub` to be a subtype of function `f` its return type must be the same type or a subtype of `R`(covariant) and its parameter must be the same or a supertype of `T` (contravariant).

Let's try to make sense of this: if you want to be able to use `fsub` where a `f` is expected (see Liskov), you need an `fsub` that can handle at most a passed argument of `T`, but nothing more specific, because that's what the callers of `f` are expected to pass to it. Moreover, since a `T` will be passed, you can be more relaxed on the parameters for your `fsub` and handle one of its supertypes, since every `T` passed to it is also an instance of its supertypes.

This is what is meant when we say that a function's argument is contravariant in its type: it tells you how its type can change in relationship subtyping the function as a whole, or actually the other way round.

---

Given this, let's get back to the specific case. The handler's mutator (`onMouseClicked_=`) should at least accept a lambda of type `MouseEvent => Unit`. Let's give it a name, `handler: MouseEvent => Unit`.

But it doesn't end here, you should expect to be able to pass the method a subtype of this lambda, and what will the type of this "subfunction" be? As we said before it could accept a `MouseEvent` or any supertype of it, then `subhandler: T => Unit` with `T :> MouseEvent`.

And that's exactly the general form of the method you saw.

#### Conclusion

I hope it became clear now that the reason why the method defines `T` as a (non-strict) supertype of `MouseEvent` is not because your handler will ever receive anything different from a `MouseEvent`, but because *you* can pass it a lambda that could be able to only handle a more abstract type of event... (e.g. you can use a `me: Any => doSomething()` )

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation of the first half of my question. What happens when I specify both an upper and lower bound, and pass in a function of `Any => Unit`, how is `T` inferred then?

Comment: I guess in the latter case `T` is inferred as `Any`, and you can't force it to be different. I suppose that you can't avoid to receive a "handler of any type" in the method, since it's an handler of Events and of MouseEvents too. The only explanation that I can imagine is that you can't force the type system to refuse a subtype of your expected lambda type, since it's just as valid by the rules of subtyping polymophism. Warn: I could be plain wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely confident about the accuracy of this answer, but here goes...

The type of `lamba` is `T => Unit`, which is sugar for [`Function1[T, Unit]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1), which is defined as:

```
trait Function1[-T1, +R]
```

`T` is used for the first parameter `T1`, which is contravariant, indicated by the `-` in `-T1`. For a contravariant parameter, the *lowest* type in the hierarchy is the most general.